# converting html design page to image in c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, png

I have done html page in asp.net and i am trying to convert whole `html page design to image(png) in c#` .can any one give me a idea.

**here is my html code :**

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div id="divpdf" runat="server">
    <table id="tid" runat="server">
    <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="this is new way of pdf" CssClass="cssformat"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Print-screen button... Paste into your favourite image editor. Quick and easy.

Comment: isnt it Print screen?